# How to get all Images in this Firebase Storage in a recyclerView or On the Logcat?

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, firebase-storage

> Here is the Screenshot of Firebase Storage :
>   [image]
>
> here is my java code :

```
 public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tools, container, false);

    recycler_view = root.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    recycler_view.setHasFixedSize(true);

    FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
    StorageReference storageReference = storage.getReference("Quotes");
    Log.e("STORAGE REF : " , String.valueOf(storageReference));


    String arr[] = new String[]{};
    for (int i =0;i<= Integer.parseInt(storageReference.getPath());i++){
    }

    ((MainActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Quran Quotes");

    final ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
    pd.setMessage("Loading");
    pd.show();
    final LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    recycler_view.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager); // set LayoutManager to RecyclerView
    quotesModelList = new ArrayList<>();
```

> I have got the Reference of Storage in the Logcat :

```
 E/STORAGE REF :: gs://mosque-614df.appspot.com/Quotes
```

Comment: you cannot get all at once you can download each file using task in a loop and you have to know the path and file name: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files

Comment: Is there a way to show all the Images inside a recyclerView ? it will be very helpful

Comment: Yes as you download each file you can add it to a data holder/adapter. and here is a library to download image from url https://github.com/bumptech/glide keep in mind first read firebase document to understand how to get downloadUrl of file then put it in Glide.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly **you have to store image download URL into firebase-database when you upload any image to firebase-store**.(When you upload any image to firebase-store, you will get image download URL on success of image upload.)

So to display list of images into recyclerView, you just have to call **reference of firebase-database** and you will get all images at once.